# RoR - redirect_to undefined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently doing an tutorial and ran into an issue with redirect.

Rails prints out the following message:

```
undefined method ` redirect_to' for #<PortfoliosController:0x00007fc6ec31b108> Did you mean? redirect_to
```

PortfolioController:

```
class PortfoliosController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @portfolio_items = Portfolio.all
  end

  def new
    @portoflio_item = Portfolio.new
  end

  def create
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new(params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :subtitle, :body))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'Portfolio was successfully created.' }

      else
        format.html { render :index }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.update(params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :subtitle, :body))
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'Portfolio item successfully updated!'}
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end








end
```

As you can see, i use redirect_to also in the def create without any problems, but def update says redirect_to is undefined?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the non-breaking space between `{` and  `redirect_to`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've typed  `redirect_to`, that's almost correct, and also Rails is telling you probably you mean `redirect_to`, then the problem is like in most of the cases, when opening curly braces, accidentally a non-breaking space is added. Unless you're using an editor that handles non-visible characters then you can realize of this, otherwise the error will be there until Rails throws the error.

Just delete the space between the `{` and `respond_to`.

For Atom see [atom-highlight-bad-chars](https://github.com/ohanhi/atom-highlight-bad-chars).
For Sublime see [Dealing with Alt+Space (non-breakable space) in Sublime Text](https://coderwall.com/p/myfhmg/dealing-with-alt-space-non-breakable-space-in-sublime-text-2-on-os-x).